# Is there a way to customize output of Doxygen index.html (and latex equivalent)?

Tags: c, doxygen, literate-programming

I am interested in writing an "introduction" on the index.html page, rather than have blank space.  Is this a feature supported by the Doxygen tool, or must I put together a hack?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is answered by the first question in the [Doxygen FAQ](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/faq.html):

> **1. How to get information on the index page in HTML?**
>
> You should use the \mainpage command inside a comment block like this:
>
> ```
> /*! \mainpage My Personal Index Page
>  *
>  * \section intro_sec Introduction
>  *
>  * This is the introduction.
>  *
>  * \section install_sec Installation
>  *
>  * \subsection step1 Step 1: Opening the box
>  *  
>  * etc...
>  */
> ```

Comment: Oh come on Oli, why would anyone look at the first question of the FAQ! :-) (+1 by the way)

Comment: Worth noting perhaps that this comment (and any other suplementary documentation) can exist in a plain text file containing only Doxygen mark-up and no code, independent of any source code file and added to the Doxygen project.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for more customised cover pages in both LaTeX and html outputs, you might also want to play with the tags `LATEX_HEADER` and `HTML_HEADER` (and `HTML_FOOTER`).